# How to execute SP using Entity Framework code-first approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I did some research in internet to know how to execute Stored Procedure using Entity Framework code-first approach. But i did not get any clear idea. Everybody is telling their own way of executing SP. In some blogs they have mentioned to execute in the following way and in other they have mentioned in a traditional ADO.NET way.

```
DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ProcedureResult>("sp_TestProcedure @param1, @param2",param1val, param2value);
```

please let me know what is the appropriate way to execute SP. I am using MVC3, Entity FW code-first approach. Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question several weeks ago and updated my answer with the solution I wound up using. Have since expanded the use a bit and am relatively happy with how clean the solution is. The results I needed would not map to my entities, so the fact that I am not returning Entities directly was not a loss for me, but may be annoying in your case if that is your intent.

See here: [Code-First Entity Framework w/ Stored Procedure returning results from complex Full-text Searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243946/code-first-entity-framework-w-stored-procedure-returning-results-from-complex-f)

Comment: Addition: If your use case was not the same as mine, I would also lean towards .edmx for just the Stored Procs as recommended by @Bob-The-Janitor below.

Answer (score 2):

As of Entity Framework 5 Strored Procedures are not supported with code first, the 2 two most common ways I know people are using them are the `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery` like you mentioned and setting up .edmx files for stored procedures, I personally lean toward using the .edmx files but that's just me

Comment: Thanx.. i prefer the first approach. in .edmx way we need to create more file to achieve that.

Answer (score -1):

quote from a book Julie Lerman wrote: 
**While Entity Framework supports mapping to stored procedures, this
functionality is not supported in Code First. The Entity Framework
team is not planning to add stored procedure support to Code First in
EF 5.0. They have indicated that there are no definite plans around when
this will be added.**

the book link on SAFARI
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449331825