# Counting matching words in Entity Framework with Linq

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Many websites, especially retail sites allow you to sort by "relevance" in the same way you can by price. I will assume this means based upon the number of words you searched for, how many of those matched the database.

For example if my relational database had a search term table and for a particular product, the 3 terms were table, tennis, club and I searched on the website for table tennis hall, I would have a 66% accuracy as 2 of the 3 matched.

I need this functionality but I'm using EF and have no idea where to begin. So, quite literally I am after the % (the 'accuracy score' or relevance).

I am happy to show my code so far, but to be honest I get the feeling throwing 70 lines of code on the page just to prove I've tried things isn't going to benefit any one so if you want the code, I'll show it, if not, can any one give me any pointers or even phrases to Google?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but, you might be interested in checking out [Lucene](http://blogs.apache.org/lucenenet/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a SQL Server project, you can begin by checking out Full Text Searching / Full Text Catalog. Using these with the `CONTAINSTABLE` or `FREETEXTTABLE` searches will return a score which is a measure of relative relevance rather than a percentage. From an EF perspective, I ended up finding the easiest solution being to call a stored procedure to get my ranked results (score and ID) outside EF and then loading the objects from the context by ID. I wrote a semi-complex Stored Procedure allowing me to weight my results based on relevance of the included field as well. I posted some of this to my question here: [Code-First Entity Framework w/ Stored Procedure returning results from complex Full-text Searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243946/code-first-entity-framework-w-stored-procedure-returning-results-from-complex-f)

Comment: hmmmm. The more I use EF, the more I feel its limitations. Yes, it's nice to have the mapping and that is worth its weight but it's very restrictive in others. I guess this is why we should not just use it just because it's new/easy to get set up etc! Thank you for the good answer although in this case, I'm on SQL Express! (sorry for not making that clear)