# Entity framework code first and stored proc

Tags: entity-framework

I apologize in advance as a I feel the answer to this question is out there, but I can't word my query properly, so I don't get much back.

Anyhow - I have a project where I mostly have a new data architecture aside from literally a couple of tables. I'd like to use EF code first. So my question is - is it possible to use code first on the majority of the project aside from a couple of classes for I which I can define stored procedures to go after tables that already exist?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can still execute SP's through your EF context. There are a bunch of examples on SO. Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243946/code-first-entity-framework-w-stored-procedure-returning-results-from-complex-f
and
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/14/code-first-4-1-using-stored-procedure-to-insert-data.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `ObjectContext` property of your `DbContext` instance in order to execute a stored procedure like so:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContext).Objectcontext.ExecuteStoreQuery<ResponseType>(
    "EXEC MyStoredProc @Value1, @Value2",
    new SqlParameter("@Value1", value1),
    new SqlParameter("@Value2", value2)
)
```

However, even if the tables exist, all you need is classes that match the tables - CodeFirst does not literally mean that the code has to exist first.  As long as your classes match the table structure and name (or you use the fluent api or annotations to make them match), you'll be fine.  Unless the stored procedures are doing something special that is hard to do in EF, I would stick to using EF consistently.